# Build works if XML is run in intellij, but command line run gets error

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, automated-tests, testng

if i run test.xml in intellj - everything is ok, test is successfully runned.

but if i try run test in command line with this code "mvn clean compile"

i get errors like this:

```
[ERROR] symbol:   class IInvokedMethod
[ERROR] location: class core.Web.RetryMethods.RetryListenerClass
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Vartotojas/Desktop/Automatiniai testia/automation/src/main/core/Web/RetryMethods/RetryListenerClass.java:[63,68] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ITestResult
[ERROR] location: class core.Web.RetryMethods.RetryListenerClass
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Vartotojas/Desktop/Automatiniai testia/automation/src/main/core/TestRail/api/DataForAPI.java:[5,1] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Vartotojas/Desktop/Automatiniai testia/automation/src/main/core/TestRail/api/DataForAPI.java:[77,96] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ITestResult
[ERROR] location: class core.TestRail.api.DataForAPI
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Vartotojas/Desktop/Automatiniai testia/automation/src/main/core/TestRail/TestRailMethods/TestCases.java:[7,1] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Vartotojas/Desktop/Automatiniai testia/automation/src/main/core/TestRail/TestRailMethods/TestCases.java:[8,1] package org.testng.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Vartotojas/Desktop/Automatiniai testia/automation/src/main/core/TestRail/TestRailMethods/TestCases.java:[58,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ISuite
```

what can i do here?
i have tryied to update testng jar, but that doesn't helped.

P.S.
Errors after scope tag is deleted:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.436 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-30T09:38:25+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/279M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project automation: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Vartotojas\Desktop\Automatiniai testia\automation\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\Users\Vartotojas\.m2\repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.2/aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar -jar C:\Users\VARTOT~1\
AppData\Local\Temp\surefire2399529717162338559\surefirebooter2518614099656505245.jar C:\Users\Vartotojas\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire2399529717162338559 2021-03-30T09-38-22_595-jvmRun1 surefire440322083299018669
4tmp surefire_04103581849292117664tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\Users\Vartotojas\.m2\repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.2/aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar -jar C:\Users\VARTOT~1\
AppData\Local\Temp\surefire2399529717162338559\surefirebooter2518614099656505245.jar C:\Users\Vartotojas\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire2399529717162338559 2021-03-30T09-38-22_595-jvmRun1 surefire440322083299018669
4tmp surefire_04103581849292117664tmp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have added a `<scope>test</scope>` when you added a `TestNG` dependency in your pom file.

This causes TestNG related classes to be visible in the class path only for your tests (i.e., all your Java code that resides in `src/test/java`)

If you remove this, then the TestNG related classes will be visible in the class path for both `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have deleted that scope tag and geting some new error. Can you check updated description, please.

Comment: You have test failures in your project. So please open up your `target/surefire-reports` folder to go through the reports to see what failed and take corrective action. Please accept the answer, if it responded to your original query